# As a reviewer of a math manuscript do you accept graph of a function as a proof for an inequality?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, functional-inequalities

Let's say I have a function $f(x)$ and an empirical approximation of the function $\tilde{f}(x)$. I cannot prove mathematically that errors is in certain bound. However, when I plot the error, the error is in certain bound. Do you accept that graph as a proof?

ps. my functions are $f(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{x-x\sin(x)} $ and $\tilde{f}(x) = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{4}{\pi(\pi/2-x)}+0.18733-0.01x$. The goal is to show $|\frac{f(x)-\tilde{f}(x)}{f(x)}|<2\times 10^{-4}$ when $0<x<\pi/2$.

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: Look at a Taylor expansion if necessary to obtain appropriate bounds.  Or anything.  Do something.  You need to be rigorous in your arguments.  Otherwise, all you are stating is conjecture.

Comment: Certainly not. Graphs serve to support your statements, not prove them. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830359/is-a-proof-also-evidence) question. As one of my old advisors used to say, a graph is not a proof. There's a difference between a mathematician and an artist.

Comment: No, because the graph may represent a very small fraction of all the possibilities and hence we can not say that what is true for small data set is also true generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly would not and I doubt any analyst worth his or her salt would on an exam, let alone a publishable paper. A graph can certainly motivate a proof,but the graph in and of itself certainly wouldn't be a proof. It certainly shouldn't be accepted as one and you're not doing the paper's author any favors by doing so. 
Send it back to him or her and tell him(her) back to the drawing board.